# Delphi EMS FireDAC: How to pass parameter from client to server using EMS?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firemonkey, firedac, ems

I am working on the simple client server application using `EMS` (i.e: for future iOS application) in Delphi.

On the client unit, I have `EMSProvider` and `EMSFireDACClient` which fetches data from a Database (MSSQL) through a Datasource.

On the server unit, I have `FDConnection` and `TFDQuery` which deals with my Database. So far everything is working fine.

**Question:** Now I need to pass some parameters from client to the server and that fetches the result data. How should I do using `EMS`? Any functions or procedures available in `EMS`?

Regarding source code, everything was handled by corresponding components. So coding part is very less.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An EMS call is like a REST call. You can pass further URL parameters both in the path (handled directly) -- see the default implementation of getting items by ID) and as extra query params. Those are in the request object. To pass them, use a custom Endpoint in the client.

Here is some more info:

Server declaration:

```
[ResourceSuffix('{item}')]
procedure GetItem(const AContext: TEndpointContext; const ARequest: TEndpointRequest; const AResponse: TEndpointResponse);
```

Server implementation:

```
procedure TNotesResource1.GetItem(const AContext: TEndpointContext; const ARequest: TEndpointRequest; const AResponse: TEndpointResponse);
var
  LItem: string;
begin
  LItem := ARequest.Params.Values['item'];
  ...
```

Client configuration for endpoint:

```
object BackendEndpointGetNote: TBackendEndpoint
  Provider = EMSProvider1
  Auth = BackendAuth1
  Params = <
    item
      Kind = pkURLSEGMENT
      name = 'item'
      Options = [poAutoCreated]
    end>
  Resource = 'Notes'
  ResourceSuffix = '{item}'
end
```

Client call:

```
  BackendEndpointGetNote.Params.Items[0].Value := AID;
  BackendEndpointGetNote.Execute;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But can you tell me a bit more about the request object and how to use custom Endpoint in the client? Any examples? (I am newbie in this topic).

Comment: I have posted a another question related to this issue in the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631077/delphi-ems-firedac-cannot-open-dataset-fdmemtable). Could you help me to solve that issue?