# Delphi EMS FireDAC: Cannot open dataset [FDMemTable]

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firemonkey, firedac, ems

I am working with a simple client server application using EMS(i.e: for future iOS application) in Delphi.

This question is the continuation of my previous question with a different error.

[This is my previous question with different problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26507557/delphi-ems-firedac-how-to-pass-parameter-from-client-to-server-using-ems) from which I have followed the suggestion given by Marco.

**Problem:** Now I have an error when I am passing parameter from client to server.

```
Project EMS_Test_Client_Project.exe raised exception class EFDException with message '[FireDAC][Comp][DS]-206. Cannot open dataset [FDMemTable]. A DataTable or a DataView must be supplied. Hint: if that is TFDMemTable, use CreateDataSet or CloneCursor to open dataset'.
```

Hereby I have an **Image1** of TFDMemTable properties (DatSTableName: *QRowParam*) with Param, which throws an error.

[image: Problem TFDMemTable]

Hereby I have an **Image2** of TFDMemTable properties (DatSTableName: *QRows*) without Param, which works.

[image: Working TFDMemTable]

**Question:** 
If I am using general call from client to server, it works and I got all the data. In which I have used **Image2** TFDMemTable without param TFDQuery. But if I am passing a parameter from client to server, then I got an error on the client side in which I have used **Image1** TFDMemTable with param TFDQuery.

Can anyone suggest me, how should I proceed further from this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Setting `Active` property to true on your `TFDMemTable` component should create the necessary memory table dataset at design time (as that is what the exception is asking for).

Comment: @TLama after setting the Active property to true on TFDMemTable component also I got the same error! Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, no other clues. I've never worked with adapters. It was just my immediate reaction for the exception you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to have a look to the EMS / FireDAC demo that ships with the product. On the client, if you don't have data you cannot open the in-memory datasets. To open them at design time you can create a "template" structure for design, matching the actual fields structure.

Comment: I am following these [EMS Client Pet docwiki link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Creating_the_EMS_Pets_Client) and [EMS Resource Pet docwiki link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Creating_the_EMS_Pets_Resource#Creating_the_Pet_Type) till now but it's without FireDAC. Could you please kindly give me the link for **EMS/FireDAC demo that ships with the product?** I couldn't find it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look under the demos, Object Pascal / Database / EMS and there is a FireDAC demo

Comment: Finally I have managed to communicate through parameter between a client and a server. Thanks for your suggestions. You are the only person helps me for Delphi and EMS kind of questions :)